# How to print variables in Tkinter using python?

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, label

```
place = Amsterdam
temp = 8.0
```

I want to make a `Label` using Tkinter that print out the place and temp. In regular code I would do:

```
print(f'place: {place}, temperature: {temp}')
```

Is there a way to do this using Tkinter?

Thanks in advance.

I tried:

```
label_1 = Label(text='place:' place )
label_1.pack()
```

But no luck

Comment: Why do you think you need something better than an f-string?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the same way in `print(...)` for the `text` option of `Label`:

```py
label_1 = Label(text=f'place: {place}, temperature: {temp}')
label_1.pack()
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to do something like this

```py
root = tk.Tk() # this opens the window
place = tkinter.StringVar()
place.set("Amsterdam")
# here place your button
tkinter.Label(root, textvariable=place).pack() # this adds the label you want
root.mainloop() # this in order to loop the window
```

You could also do this, if you don't want to pass a variable into the label, but want the label to be constant

```py
root = tk.Tk() # this opens the window
# here place your button
tkinter.Label(root, text="YourText").pack() # this adds the label you want
root.mainloop() # this in order to loop the window
```

Comment: Is it possible to do both the place and temperature in the same label?

Comment: Do you mean like next to each other? If yes, you could easily just create one string instead of 2 and put that one string in